# iOS Keychain values not loaded/stored

Tags: ios, ios7, keychain

I have an app that uses Keychain to store passwords and several other user-related information.
All is working well, but i just discovered i have some customers that are unable to retrieve their data on their iPad.
i've made them some patch that stores the given data and retrieves it, but it fails (not sure if on the store or retrieve part).
since i'm distanced, i can't debug this problem properly. My question is - are you familiar with such issues, and where/what should i start looking for.
my application is for iPad and works on iOS7 SDK
Any ideas would be welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: Try to identify if their iPad are jailbroken, the iOS version, etc.

Comment: Follows Larme suggestion, I add another one: tell your clients if they have uninstalled / reinstalled the application before performing the test.

Comment: @Larme, (and Marco Pace) - can you elaborate on the problems in each of these thing? (for example - why should iOS version matter). Thanks

Comment: @MarcoPace  - they did reinstall the app before the use - but the data is being saved after the re-installation.  i try the same process myself but don't get any problem

Comment: Well, it will help narrow down on what circumstances it doesn't work. You said you tested on iOS7, but your never mentioned if your app is released also for iOS6. Plus sometimes jailbreaken devices could caused issues.

Comment: The application is released for iOS7 only.